# Google SignIn Android not working in release mode

Tags: android, google-signin

In my app, in debug mode Google sign in works perfectly. But after releasing it to play-store, its not working.

What i have done -- Added the debug `sha1`, `release sha1` and google app sign in `sha1` in fire-base.

But after that also its not working.

Checked various stack-overflow post, in maximum posts the solution is the debug and release key to be added in fire-base. So what will be my solution as i already implemented all the 3 `sha1` keys then also its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding SHA-256 worked for me. Now its working fine. Thanks anyways guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled google play app signing, Try adding google app signing SHA1 key in the firebase console.[image]